# How to delete data from linked list?

Tags: c

I'm trying to delete a data from linked list loaded from drivers.txt and I haven't got any ideas to how to do it...

So to imagine this is my **drivers.txt** file.

```
***
Carl
RedBull
***
John
Mercedes
***
Jessica
Mercedes
***
Brandon
RedBull
```

I'm trying to remove every driver driving for RedBull. So when I print next time I want to see only John and Jessica.

My struct:

```c
typedef struct drivers {
    char                *name;
    char                *team;
    struct drivers      *next;
} drivers_t;
```

How I load the drivers.txt.

```c
drivers_t *drivers_load(const char *file){
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("drivers.txt", "r");
    drivers_t *ptr = NULL;
    drivers_t *head = NULL;

    char buffer[255];
    while (fgets(buffer, 255, fp) != NULL){
        switch(i++){
        case 0:
            if( !ptr ) {
                ptr = drivers_new();
                head = ptr;
            }
            else {
                ptr->next = drivers_new();
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            ptr->name = strdup(buffer);
            break;
        case 2:
            ptr->team = strdup(buffer);
            break;

            i = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

My print function:

```c
void drivers_print(drivers *head){
    int number = 1;
    for (drivers_t *drivers = head; drivers != NULL; drivers = drivers->next){
        printf("%d.\n", number++);
        printf("Driver: %s", drivers->presenter);
        printf("Team: %s", drivers->birth_number);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Deleting node:

```c
void node_delete(drivers_t *head){
    char team[32];

    scanf("%s", &team);
    strcat(team, "\n");

    for (node_t *node = head; node != NULL; node = node->next){
        if(strcmp(node->team, team) == 0){
            drivers_t *temp;
            temp = head->next;
            head->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
        }
        else{}
    }
}
```

Comment: To get one node out of the list, you change the `next` pointer of the _previous_ element to point one node further ahead (so it skips the one to remove).

Comment: You wrote _"I'm trying to delete..."_: Well there is no attempt to delete anything in the code you posted. What have you tried and how did it fail? Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: @Jabberwocky I know that I havent posted a code, but its because I think its too bad to share...I have no idea how to delete a node

Comment: @Erri000 if you want answers about your poor code you wrote, you need to show that code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i was trying few sites with codes to delete specific node, but I cant implement them into mine... so i updated the code and i dunno ...

Comment: @Erri000 you're on the right track with your `node_delete` function. Using a piece of paper, a pencil and the answer below, you should be able to figure it out. Also read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Jabberwocky trying for few hours, but it takes too much time...i can find these nodes which i want to delete but i cant delete them properly... anyway thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list like this:

`A -> B -> C -> D -> E`

and you want to delete `C`, all you need to do is to ensure that the `next` pointer of `B` now points to `D`, so you get:

`A -> B -> D -> E`

Basically the algorithm is:

1. Go down the list and find `C`, the node you want to remove.
2. While going down the list, always also remember the last node you have seen, which would be `B` in that case.
3. Once you reached `C`, assign the `next` pointer value of `C` to the `next` pointer value of `B` and you are done, as now going over the list directly jumps from `B` to `D`.
4. Finally clean up `C`, which means free any memory `C` or any of its struct fields are using.

The only tricky case is the first node, as removing `A` is a special case, in which case you must set the list pointer itself to the `next` value of `A`, so the list now starts with `B`. You can recognize that case easily, though, as in step (2) you have remembered the last node. When you start, there is no last node, so initially that value should start with `NULL`. If you found the node (step 3) and the last one is `NULL`, you will know that you just hit the first node and you can handle that case appropriately.